# How do I pass an argument that is a string array to my Cake script?

Tags: cakebuild

I want to get an `Argument<IEnumerable<string>>` (or `string[]`, or whatever - an iterable list of strings) to my Cake script, but I can't figure out how to pass it from `build.ps1` to `cake.exe`.

This is what I have so far:

**In build.ps1:**

```
param(
    # ...
    [ValidateSet("Bar", "Baz")]
    [string[]]$Foo
)

# ...

$fooArg = If ($Foo.Count -gt 0) {"-foo=`(`"{0}`"`)" -f [string]::Join("`",`", $Foo)} Else {""}
Invoke-Expression "$CAKE_EXE ... $fooArg"
```

**In build.cake:**

```
var baz = Argument<IEnumerable<string>>("foo", new string[0]);
```

However, when I execute this, I get the following error:

> More than one build script specified.
>
> Could not find a build script to execute.
>   Either the first argument must the build script's path,
>   or build script should follow default script name conventions.
>
> Usage: Cake.exe [build-script] [-verbosity=value]
>                  [-showdescription] [-dryrun] [..]
>
> Example: Cake.exe
>   Example: Cake.exe build.cake -verbosity=quiet
>   Example: Cake.exe build.cake -showdescription
>
> Options:
>      -verbosity=value    Specifies the amount of information to be displayed.
>                          (Quiet, Minimal, Normal, Verbose, Diagnostic)
>      -showdescription    Shows description about tasks.
>      -dryrun             Performs a dry run.
>      -version            Displays version information.
>      -help               Displays usage information.
>      -experimental       Uses the nightly builds of Roslyn script engine.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

**Solution #1 (simple):**

You could solve it simply by accepting the argument as a string and split it:

```
var foo = Argument("foo", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

**Solution #2 (complex):**

You could also solve this by wrapping the string array in a custom type and implement 
a `TypeConverter` for that type. Both the wrapper and the type converter would have to 
reside in a .NET assembly that would be loaded either via the `#r` or `#addin` directive.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringArrayConverter))]
public class StringArray
{
    public string[] Items { get; }
}

public class StringArrayConverter : TypeConverter
{
  // Implementation here :)
}
```

You would then use the `Argument` alias as usual with the `StringArray` type.

```
var foo = Argument<StringArray>("foo", null);
```

In my opinion, this option is a little bit complex for getting a string array so you might want to go with the simpler solution until [we've added IEnumerable support for arguments](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/728).