# How to pass multiple flags as a Cake argument?

Tags: c#, build, enums, cakebuild

We have a number of build flags we'd like to be able to pass to our Cake script as a single argument. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735090) answer and the [TypeConverter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=net-5.0), I would expect the following simplified code to compile and run.

```cs
public class BuildFlagsConverter : TypeConverter
{
  public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
  {
    return BuildFlags.None;
  }
}

[Flags]
[TypeConverter(typeof(BuildFlagsConverter))]
enum BuildFlags
{
  None = 0,
  FeatureOne = 1,
  FeatureTwo = 2,
  All = FeatureOne | FeatureTwo,
}

var buildFlags = Argument<BuildFlags>("buildFlags", BuildFlags.All);
```

I would then expect to be able to call `cake --buildFlags="FeatureOne|FeatureTwo"` to build. Instead, Cake is throwing the following error:

> Error: One or more errors occurred. (FeatureOne|FeatureTwo is not a valid value for BuildFlags.)

I thought this might be related to using an enum instead of a class, so I tried converting `BuildFlags` to a static class with static getters for each of the above values. However, in this case I was still getting an error:

> Error: One or more errors occurred. (TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String.)

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this? Ideally, we would still get the `enum` syntax within the script itself, but I suppose I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

After troubleshooting, it seems that using custom type converters works well on .NET, .NET Core, and .NET Framework, but does not work well on Mono.

Reported as a bug - https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/3333

---

Is it possible that you're using an old version of Cake that doesn't support custom type converters?

I tested your code on the latest version of Cake as of this writing (1.1.0) and it worked as expected.

[image: Cake Type Converter example run]

[image: Cake Type Converter example run on MacOS]

---

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

public class BuildFlagsConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return BuildFlags.None;
    }
}

[Flags]
[TypeConverter(typeof(BuildFlagsConverter))]
enum BuildFlags
{
    None = 0,
    FeatureOne = 1,
    FeatureTwo = 2,
    All = FeatureOne | FeatureTwo,
}

var buildFlags = Argument<BuildFlags>("buildFlags", BuildFlags.All);
Information("buildFlags converted to: {0}", buildFlags);
```

Comment: Yep, we're on 0.38.5 and I hadn't considered that this was a (relatively) recent addition. Guess it's time to upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, after updating to Cake 1.1.0 I'm not seeing the same behavior you showed; invoking Cake with `--buildFlags="FeatureOne|FeatureTwo"` is still giving the same "not a valid value" error I shared above. I've even copied your script just to verify.

Comment: @steverichey Do you want to put a repro project on a GitHub repo? As you saw on the screenshots above... It worked on my Windows VM.

Comment: My setup is identical to what you posted, but I'm on macOS 11.3.1, so I'm guessing that's causing a problem on my end.

Comment: @steverichey Works for me on MacOS 11.2.3 with Cake v1.1.0 Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cupdr.png

Comment: I don't think I have Cake installed the same way you do, I have it installed via homebrew. Regardless, it's the same version of Cake, just a somewhat different version of macOS: https://i.imgur.com/t6MOqHk.png


_edit_: Using `dotnet cake` does work! However, getting Cake from the bootstrapper does not, which is ultimately what I need to work for our CI systems.

Comment: @steverichey I can reproduce the error you see with the Homebrew version of Cake. My guess is that it's an issue with Mono not being able to see the type converters in the compiled Cake script, which is not a problem when running in .NET. I'm tracking it as a bug in the main repo https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/3333 but it's unlikely that it will be fixed given that our general recommendation is to move to the .NET Tool in your CI systems - https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/runners/dotnet-tool and we'll eventually sunset the other Cake runners